# match non-unique, un-sorted array to indexes in unique, sorted array

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy

I have a sorted, unique numpy character array:

```
import numpy as np
vocab = np.asarray(['a', 'aaa', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

I have another, unsorted array (I actually have millions of these):

```
sentence = np.asarray(['b', 'aaa', 'b', 'aaa', 'b', 'z'])
```

This second array is much smaller than the first array, and also potentially contains values not in the original array.

What I want to do is match the values in the second array to their corresponding indexes, returning `nan` or some special value for non-matches.

e.g.:

```
sentence_idx = np.asarray([2, 1, 2, 1, 2, np.nan])
```

I've tried a couple different iterations of a matching function with np.in1d, but it always seems to break down on sentences that contain repeated words.

I've also tried a couple of different list comprehensions, but they're too slow to run on my collection of millions of sentences.

So, what's the best way to accomplish this in numpy?  In R, I'd use the [match](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) function, but there seems to be no numpy equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nifty tool for such searches [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), like so -

```
# Store matching indices of 'sentence' in 'vocab' when "left-searched"
out = np.searchsorted(vocab,sentence,'left').astype(float)

# Get matching indices of 'sentence' in 'vocab' when "right-searched".
# Now, the trick is that non-matches won't have any change between left 
# and right searches. So, compare these two searches and look for the 
# unchanged ones, which are the invalid ones and set them as NaNs.
right_idx = np.searchsorted(vocab,sentence,'right')
out[out == right_idx] = np.nan
```

Sample run -

```
In [17]: vocab = np.asarray(['a', 'aaa', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']) 
    ...: sentence = np.asarray(['b', 'aaa', 'b', 'aaa', 'b', 'z'])
    ...: 

In [18]: out = np.searchsorted(vocab,sentence,'left').astype(float)
    ...: right_idx = np.searchsorted(vocab,sentence,'right')
    ...: out[out == right_idx] = np.nan
    ...: 

In [19]: out
Out[19]: array([  2.,   1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,  nan])
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Quick question, how does `np.searchsorted` decide what to return for non-matchest?  E.g. `np.searchsorted(vocab,sentence,'left').astype(float)` returns 7 in the last position.

Comment: @Zach It looks where to put that element (last element in this case) in an alphabetically sorted array. `z` being the last letter and since nothing in `vocab` is `z`, thus there's no element in `vocab` at the left of which that `z` could be put. So, `z`'s index output would be `len(vocab)+1`. Consider another case : You have `'_'` instead of `'z'`. In this, with that alphabetical sorting and no matches, it would be `0`. Consider yet another case : We have `'a'` instead of `'z'`. Again, index o/p would be `0`. But this time, the seacrshorted(...'right') would be different than for `'_'` case.